# How to build a serial (RS422 or RS232) message to communicate with Sick LMS200 via PuTTy?

Tags: networking, serial-port

I have a serial device (sick LMS200) connected to my PC using a RS422 to USB converter. The serial settings (baud, stop bits, etc...) on the LMS200 and my PC match and are communicating (verified using an application that ships with the LMS200). I need to write a custom application which communicates with the LMS.

Before I can begin building my application I need to figure out how to exchange datagrams between the PC and the LMS. To figure this out I have been trying to manually send datagrams using PuTTy. The manual for the LMS ( https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Byv4owwJZnRYVUJPMXdud0Z6Uzg) defines the datagram types and how they should be built. For example, on pg 46 of the manual it is possible to see a datagram that sends a specific instruction to the unit; it looks like this: `02 00 02 00 30 01 31 18`.

However when I use PuTTy to send the string `02 00 02 00 30 01 31 18` the LMS does not respond (which it should). I believe it does not respond because the datagram is missing either some serial header data or I am not representing the hex values correctly (I tried to represent bytes such as`00` using `0x00` and `00h` but had no success). Can you please help me formulate a valid serial message using the manual? I have been at this for a very long time and I am having a really hard time understanding how to convert the information in the manual into a valid datagram.

Please let me know if I can provide any more info. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are no things like frames or packets for serial communications. You can have something like terminal standards, e.g. VT-100, or a proprietary protocol.

Comment: Well yes, this is a proprietary protocol, VT-100 was a proprietary protocol. You aren't sending the literal string "02 00 02..." are you? You should probably send the byte value 02 hex then 00 hex, etc. i.e. A single byte/character for each pair of digits. That might be challenging to do with putty, not sure how you get it to send 00 (nul).  You might try snooping on the communication between the app and the device - that way perhaps you can figure out what extra information is needed around your packet for it to be accepted by the device.

Comment: @barny unfortunately, yes I am sending the literal string. how do I differentiate between 02 decimal and 02 hex? both `0x02` and `02h` did not work. should I represent 02 as `00000010`? any other ideas?

Comment: *"both 0x02 and 02h did not work."* -- You're not making any sense, because you make no distinction between byte values, ASCII characters and strings.  @barny *"not sure how you get it to send 00 (nul)"* -- The typical USA terminal keyboard can generate an ASCII NUL character by typing ctrl-@, or holding down the `CTRL` and `Shift` keys and typing `2`.  For SOH or  `0x01` type ctrl-A, et cetra.  When you don't know how to generate the ASCII control characters from the keyboard, you could fall back on creating the message in a file using a hex editor (not a text editor), and then send the file.

Comment: @sawdust you sir, are absolutely correct! I spent the whole day figuring this out. And actually your answer with `CTRL` + `SHIFT`+ `B` for 0x02 answers my question. If you provide your answer I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not representing the hex values correctly (I tried to represent bytes such as00 using 0x00 and 00h but had no success).

The `Ctrl` key on terminal/PC keyboards can be used to generate ASCII control characters (i.e. the unprintable characters with byte values of `0x00` through `0x1F`).
Just like the `Shift` key generates the shifted or uppercase character of the key (instead of its unshifted or lower-case character), the `Ctrl` key (with an alphabetic or a few other keys) can generate an ASCII control character.

The typical USA PC keyboard can generate an ASCII 'NUL' character by typing ctrl-@, that is, by holding down the `CTRL` and `Shift` keys, and typing `2` (since the '@' character is the shifted character of the `2` key on USA PC keyboards).

In similar fashion for 'SOH' or `0x01` type ctrl-A (i.e. `CTRL`+`A` keys, the `Shift` is not necessary), for 'STX' or `0x02` type ctrl-B, *et cetera*.
For 'SUB' or `0x1A` type ctrl-Z.
For 'ESC' or `0x1B` type the `Esc` key.
For 'FS' or `0x1C` type ctrl-\ (or `CTRL`+`\`).
For 'GS' or `0x1D` type ctrl-] (or `CTRL`+`]`).
For 'RS' or `0x1E` type ctrl-^ (or `CTRL`+`Shift`+`6`).
For 'US' or `0x1F` type ctrl-_ (or `CTRL`+`Shift`+`-`).

Note that a few oft-used ASCII control codes have dedicated keys, e.g.
    'HT' has the `Tab` key for `0x09`,
    'BS' has the `Backspace` key for `0x08`,
    'LF' has the `Enter` key (in Linux) for `0x0A`,  and
    'ESC' has the `Esc` key for `0x1B`.

---

When you don't know how to generate the ASCII control characters from the keyboard, you could fall back on creating the message in a file using a hex editor (not a text editor), and then send the file.

Actually the binary file could be the most reliable method of hand-generation of binary messages.  Hand-typing of control codes could fail when a code is intercepted by the shell or application program as a special directive to it (e.g. ctrl-C or ctrl-Z to abort the program) rather than treating it as data.
Escaping the input data is one method that might be available to avoid this.
Phone modems have managed to avoid this issue when in transparent (aka data) mode, by requiring a time guard (i.e. specific idle times) to separate and differentiate commands from data.

Answer (score 1):

The way to get this done is to:

(1) download HexEdit software, and create a file containing HEX values (not decimal reprsentations of the ascii table - where the number 2 was being tramitted as 32)

(2) use Tera Term software to then send the file over the serial line.